# File Name in french letters garbled on attachment

Tags: spring

I am using spring JavaMailSender for sending mail. All works fine except for attaching file with filename in diacritic letters. i am storing the file in particular location under JBOSS directory. Issue occur during the attachment. I gone through the solutions given similar for my question But nothing helps me. Can please someone give me a solution for this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting the charset to UTF-8 like this: msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8"); msg.setText(message, "UTF-8");

Comment: No Luck Matrium. thanks for your response.